# export whole module as default export

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

Hey so i have this module i made where i can import it like this:

```
import * as Foo from "foo.ts"
```

But whenever i try to import it as so:

```
import Foo from "foo.ts"
```

I get an error from VSCode because i don't have a default export in my module, i'd like to export the whole module in the default module so that `import Foo from "foo.ts"` results in the same as `import * as Foo from "foo.ts"`, is this possible without making another file containing something like the following?

```
import * as Foo from "foo.ts"
export default Foo
```

And of course then using `import Foo from "foo2.ts"` instead of `import Foo from "foo.ts"`

Comment: `export default { A, B, C, ... }` inside `Foo`.

Comment: Yeah but isn't there something more elegant that will automatically export everything in it dynamically, without manually updating it with every single item i export otherwise?